# ASP.NET Core 2.1: how to access "action claims" in the controller code (especially during user registration)?

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-identity

Using Core Identity OAuth2 authentication (and retrieving user info) last MS samples uses such code:

```
   options.Events = new OAuthEvents
   {   
       // ...
       OnCreatingTicket = async (OAuthCreatingTicketContext context) =>
       {
          var userInfo = // ..
          context.RunClaimActions(userInfo);
       }
   }
```

MS call it "Action Claims".

But how to access those action claims later, in the controller code ? 
To be concrete, how to access them in the "Core Identity 2.1"  generated Razor pages user external login `OnGetCallbackAsync`

```
// ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetCallbackAsync(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
 {
         var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity; 
         var claimsPrincipal = User.Identity as ClaimsPrincipal; // null
         // claimsIdentity doesn't contains oauth target claims (since this new not registered yet user?)
         // ..
         var signInResult = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(...);
        if (signInResult.Succeeded)
        {
        }else // means yet not registered locally 
        {
            // HOW TO ACCESS ACTION CLAIMS THERE?
            // or how to get authentication token to get user info manually...
        }
  }
```

**P.S.**
Additionally to the asnwer: `RunClaimActions` should be used together with `MapJsonKey`

```
serviceCollection.AddAuthentication().AddOAuth(options =>
            { 
              // ...
                    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.claims.claimtypes_members.aspx

                    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Surname, "family_name");
                    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "given_name");
                    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("SalesforceOrganizationId", "organization_id");
```

Then userinfo fields can be accessed as regular user claims. Therefore "Action claims" are not "special type of claims" but just "yet another ASP MVC magic".

Also do not forget about `options.SaveTokens = true;` Only with it you will be able to get token as

```
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
var token = info.AuthenticationTokens ()[0];
```

and get more information from other connected services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this example in official documentation.

Reference [Persist additional claims and tokens from external providers in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

You would first have to map the desired claims when configuring the authentication provider

The documentation example used Google's, where it map user data keys and create claims

> In the provider's options, specify a `MapJsonKey` for each key in the external provider's JSON user data for the app identity to read on sign in.

*Startup*

```cs
services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(options => {

    //....

    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Gender, "gender");
    //...map other claims/claim types

    //...
}
```

And from there you should be able to access claims via the `ExternalLoginInfo.Principal` which has the `ClaimsPrincipal` representing the user associated with the login.

*ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs*

```cs
//Executes when a previously registered user signs into the app.
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetCallbackAsync(
    string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null) {
    if (remoteError != null) {
        ErrorMessage = $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}";
        return RedirectToPage("./Login");
    }

    // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
    var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (info == null) {
        return RedirectToPage("./Login");
    }

    // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user 
    // already has a login
    var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(
        info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, 
        bypassTwoFactor : true);

    if (result.Succeeded) {
        // Store the access token and resign in so the token is included in
        // in the cookie
        var user = await _userManager.FindByLoginAsync(info.LoginProvider, 
            info.ProviderKey);

        // What is the gender of this user if present
        if (info.Principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Gender)) {
            var gender = info.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Gender);
            //...use gender
        }

        var props = new AuthenticationProperties();
        props.StoreTokens(info.AuthenticationTokens);

        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, props, info.LoginProvider);

        _logger.LogInformation(
            "{Name} logged in with {LoginProvider} provider.", 
            info.Principal.Identity.Name, info.LoginProvider);

        return LocalRedirect(Url.GetLocalUrl(returnUrl));
    }

    if (result.IsLockedOut) {
        return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
    } else {
        // If the user does not have an account, then ask the user to 
        // create an account
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        LoginProvider = info.LoginProvider;

        if (info.Principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email)) {
            Input = new InputModel {
                Email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)
            };
        }

        return Page();
    }
}
```

Review the comments in the code and note the access to `info.Principal.Identity`, which should contain the claims associated with the current user after resigning in.

Comment: Situation: we get to the part of code that is started with comment:

   // If the user does not have an account, then ask the user to 
   // create an account

And there are no userIfo claims in the `info.Principal` claims list added by `RunClaimActions`. There is email, but it will be there  even if we do not call `RunClaimActions` :((

Comment: :(( So when you write "should contain " - in reality no user claims obtained. And I know that `userInfo ` on `OnCreatingTicket ` was not empty - i see it in the debugger.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij at that point there will be no claims, as the user has no account. On a success path, the claims will be retrieved and added to the principle.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. But I need those claims on account registration. We are talking about not existed local account - but remote oauth account exists and had just sended me its userinfo (in `OnCreatingTicket `).  So I want to say "hello, first name last name" and so on during the registration. Very clear and common use case. How to get them?

If `OnCreatingTicket ` is wrong place to return userInfo when registering user, how to get authentication token and call user info service manually? The tokens list is also null at this place of code.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij ok cool. Can you update the original question with those detail so as to clarify what it is you are actually trying to do so it does not look like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The current answer was based on the detail provided and since you were referring to `OnGetCallbackAsync` which *`Executes when a previously registered user signs into the app.`*, the assumption was made that you were at that point in the flow.

Comment: Ok ,I will do it. I thougth that clue is understanding what are "action claims". But if we come from solving practical problem - i will specify it better.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij, quick note from the link I provided earlier, which should provide some context `OnPostConfirmationAsync – Executes for new user registration.`

Comment: OnPostConfirmationAsync  is used after user confirmed registration. But I want to have userinfo before building confirmation dialog.  That is in `OnGetCallbackAsync`

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij have you mapped the desired claims from the provider? Did you review the linked article in the answer?

Comment: @nikosi,  how can I map claims from the providers and how it is related to the action claims? Unfortunatly I can't understand this article - it is full of magic. E.g how to access claims OnPostConfirmationAsync ?  info.Principal (info there ExternalLoginInfo) ?  What I see info.Principal.Claims is is the same as it was early on OnGetCallbackAsync . No userinfo claims added by RunClaimActions.

Comment: Ok , I've found this line in doc `options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Gender, "gender");` I should get deeper to know what does it mean. Thank you.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij that is correct. depending on the provider you map the necessary keys so that they will be added as claims that can be access as needed.